# Mage armor and unconscious condition

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, unconscious

If I as a wizard cast Mage Armor on my monk friend, then the monk is rendered unconscious by a group of nasty skeletons, will the Mage Armor still be in effect when our lovely cleric heals him and he stands up?

Comment: @Avaro, which PC is falling unconscious and later getting healed in your example? Is it the monk, or the wizard?

Answer (score 16):

*Mage armor*, like virtually every buff spell, has a duration.  It lasts for its duration, or until dispelled.

*Mage armor* doesn't end because its target became unconscious.  It continues to apply even WHILE they are unconscious.  An unconscious, prone, *mage armor*ed target is still four AC points harder to hit than the same target would be if not *mage armor*ed.  It's a great away for an arcane caster to protect a downed ally from ranged attacks until they can get a healer (or at least someone with the Heal skill) to him.

*Mage armor* also is not a concentration-duration spell, and so it doesn't end if it's caster is unconscious.  Once cast, it sustains itself and doesn't require the wizard who cast it in order to continue to exist - at least, until its duration is up and it vanishes.  Even if the wizard dies, the spell effect will continue until dispelled or it expires.

TL;DR:  **No matter who gets knocked unconscious, *mage armor* will continue to function so long as its duration has not expired, it has not been dispelled**, and the creature it was cast on is still alive, and maybe even if they've died.

Comment: Note: since spells do not generally check for (continued) target validity after being cast, there should be no particular reason (RAW) for *mage armor* to end even on death.